# Verification that a function satisfies a PDE

Tags: probability-theory, partial-differential-equations, stochastic-calculus, stochastic-analysis, stochastic-differential-equations

Consider the problem
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial v^{\epsilon}(t,x)}{\partial t}= L^{\epsilon}v^{\epsilon}(t,x)+c(x)v^{\epsilon}(t,x)+g(x); \quad t>0, \: x \in \mathbb{R}^r \\
v^{\epsilon}(0,x)=f(x) \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
for $\epsilon > 0$,together with the problem for the first-order operator which is obtained for $\epsilon = 0$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
\frac{\partial v^{0}(t,x)}{\partial t}= L^{0}v^{0}(t,x)+c(x)v^{0}(t,x)+g(x); \quad t>0, \: x \in \mathbb{R}^r \\
v^{0}(0,x)=f(x) \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Consider then the SDE: $dX_{t}^{\epsilon,x}=b(X_{t}^{\epsilon, x})dt+\epsilon \sigma(X_{t}^{\epsilon,x})dW_t$, where $W$ is a Wiener process and

$
L^{\epsilon}= \frac{\epsilon^2}{2} \sum_{i,j=1}^{r}a^{i,j}(x)\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^i \partial x^j} + \sum_{i=1}^{r}b^i(x)\frac{\partial}{\partial x^i}
$

with $\sigma(x)\sigma^t(x)=a^{i,j}(x)$.

I proved that
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
\lim_{\epsilon \to 0} v^{\epsilon}(t,x) &= f(X_{t}^{0,x})\exp\biggl\{ \int_{0}^{t}c(X_{s}^{0,x})ds \biggr\} \\
&+ \int_{0}^{t} g(X_{s}^{0,x})\exp \biggl\{ \int_{0}^{s}c(X_{v}^{0,x})dv \biggr\} ds
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
and now I have to show that the right-hand side is the solution of the second Cauchy problem (the one with $epsilon = 0$). I know that I have to compute the derivatives and substitute but I'm having some trouble. Here's what I came up with:

$
\frac{\partial v^0}{\partial t}= f(X_{t}^{0,x})c(X_{t}^{0,x})e^{\int_{0}^{t}c(X_{s}^{0,x})ds}+g(X_{t}^{0,x})e^{\int_{0}^{t}c(X_{s}^{0,x})ds}
$

$
L^0v^0 = \frac{\partial f}{\partial X}(X_{t}^{0,x})e^{\int c(X_{s}^{0,x})ds}+f(X_{t}^{0,x})c(X_{t}^{0,x})e^{\int c(X_{s}^{0,x})ds}+g(X_{t}^{0,x})e^{\int c(X_{s}^{0,x})ds}
$

If I substitute in the second problem and sum all the terms up, I'm left with
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial X}(X_{t}^{0,x})e^{\int_{0}^{t} c(X_{s}^{0,x})ds}+f(X_{t}^{0,x})c(X_{t}^{0,x})e^{\int_{0}^{t} c(X_{s}^{0,x})ds}+c(X_{t}^{0,x})\int_{0}^{t}g(X_{s}^{0,x})e^{\int_{0}^{s} c(X_{v}^{0,x})dv}ds+g(X_{t}^{0,x})=0
\end{equation}

Is what I did until now correct? If so how do I conclude? If not how do I fix it to get the desired solution? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When you compute $\frac{\partial v^0(t,x)}{\partial t}$, you clearly forgot the term $\nabla f(X^{0,x}_t) \cdot b(X^{0,x}_t) \exp\left[\int_0^t c(X^{0,x}_s) \mathrm{d}s\right]$, where the gradient is taken with respect to the space variable only...